# google +1 function in iphone app without UIWebView?

Tags: api, uiwebview, google-plus-one

I know I can add google +1 in the app via UIWebView + JavaScript

But does google +1 have a REST api? I won't use UIWebView in my app and wish to keep consistence in this way. So I would like to create my own UIButton and use +1 as I wish

Anyone knows how?

Thanks